# Remove Duplicate/Similar Data from Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I am attempting to remove duplicate data from a model [This is a scorecard. There can be multiple users on a single scorecard. Session ID represents a SINGLE scorecard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZViMs.png)

I would like to group the session ID's together and display a single bootstrap card for each session. Sort of like this... [This is still showing a card for multipole session 1 ID's. I need 1 card for every different session ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/przid.png)

I have tried nesting a second foreach within my first in attempt to loop through the sessionId's `@foreach (var item in Model)

```
        {

            foreach (var session in item.SessionId)
            {
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">

                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <p class="card-text text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }





        }`
```

I created a variable which checked the last iteration of the sessionId and compared it to the current one`@foreach (var item in Model)

```
        {
            var lastitem = Model.Last();

            if (item.SessionId != lastitem.SessionId)
            {
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">

                        <h5 class="card-title text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <p class="card-text text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }





        }`
```

I have also attempted using a for loop...

```
<div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            @for (int i = Model.FirstOrDefault().SessionId; i < Model.Count(); i = i + 1)
            {
                <div>@i</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have only 8 session Id numbers (1-8) but there are multiple session Id's for each session (i.e. 36 session 1 id's). so when I target the Model.Count() it returns a huge array.

In attempt to counter this, I tried...

```
<div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            @for (int i = Model.FirstOrDefault().SessionId; i < Model.Distinct().FirstOrDefault().SessionId; i = i + 1)
            {
                <div>@i</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

I attempted to target the selected items Distinct Session Id but it returned nothing.

Comment: And what have you done so far? Share your efforts and others will help you perfect it but you have to have something to work on. SO is not made to implement ideas.

Comment: Please don't add images of code, add your actual code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
@for (int s = Model.Distinct().FirstOrDefault().SessionId; s <= Model.Distinct().LastOrDefault().SessionId; s = s + 1)
        {
```

}

Which gives me only the 8 sessions I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<T> withDupes = LoadData();
List<T> noDupes = withDupes.Distinct().ToList();
```

use this and return your new model without dupes, after that use foreach for the table :)

ps: if your list is huge, dont use Razor. Return a json object and use a plugin like datatable.js ;)

See ya